# db2 federation pull up wrong date from oracle

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

We are pulling data from `Oracle 11gR2` database into `db2 version 11.1.4.4` via **federation**. All data are fetched correctly **except DATE type data**.

When session connects to Db2 and execute the below query it give wrong date data for the first time.

But when we execute it again in the same session it retrieves correct date data after that.

db2: `select PROCESS_TIME from test.ut  fetch first 2 rows only`

```
PROCESS_TIME
--------------------------
12=:-<=-90-00.00.00.000000  
12=:-<=-90-00.00.00.000000

  2 record(s) selected.
```

db2: `select PROCESS_TIME from test.ut where ...  fetch first 2 rows only`

```
PROCESS_TIME
--------------------------
2019-07-12-09.42.53.000000  
2019-07-12-09.42.53.000000

  2 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Why have you tagged db2-400?  EDIT your question to show the full command used when doing the `create server` (to show the options used).

Comment: Also show the Oracle column data-type, and the datatype for the matching column  in the Db2 nickname.

Answer (score 1):

You may hit still open APAR [IT28205](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1IT28205).

Comment: Fix should be included in next fix pack, workaround is to explicitly alter the session and set date format:
```
SET PASSTHRU <server_name>
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
SET PASSTHRU RESET
```

Comment: Hi kkuduk, 

db2 SET PASSTHRU remote_db_server
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

db2 "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

I am getting below error:
db2 "select process_time from test.table_name fetch first 2 rows only"
SQL1822N  Unexpected error code "933" received from data source "remote_db_server".
Associated text and tokens are "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ".
SQLSTATE=560BD

Comment: @Mao Create server command:

CREATE SERVER "remote_server" 
   TYPE ORACLE 
   VERSION '11.0' 
   WRAPPER "NET8"  
   OPTIONS
     (NODE  'EIWODS'
     ,PASSWORD  'Y'
     ,PUSHDOWN  'Y'
     );

Comment: Oracle column data type is date

Comment: @kkuduk, we are on latest fixpack 4a for db2 version 11.1.4.4

Comment: @Masheed fix is not available yet in any fix pack, it will be in next one . Did you run "PASSTHRU RESET" before the query?

Comment: @kkuduk,
Same error. /<br>

**db2 set passthru reset**
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.  
**db2 set passthru remote_db_server**   
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.  
**db2 "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'"**  
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.  
**db2 "select process_time from test.table_name fetch first 2 rows only"**  
SQL1822N  Unexpected error code "933" received from data source
"remote_db_server ". Associated text and tokens are "ORA-00933: SQL command not
properly ended ".  SQLSTATE=560BD

Comment: @Masheed,
The order should be different. First you enable passthru, then change the NLS_DATE and only then run RESET.

Comment: @kkuduk, I have checked with both options:
**1.** enable passthru, alter session to nls_date then run, it not works
**2.** Reset passthru, enable passthru, alter session to nls_date then run, it not works

Comment: I think we might need a more verbose format and cover TIMESTAMP, just in case. Try:

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'